# Use inotifywait -m in script without creating extra process?

Tags: linux, bash, process, inotify

I am not sure this is possible, but I've often thought that and some solutions have amazed me. Is it possible to create the equivalent of the following script without creating two processes (in this case, it is clear two processes are created because there is a pipe):

```
#!/bin/bash

EVENTS="CREATE,CLOSE_WRITE,DELETE,MODIFY,MOVED_FROM,MOVED_TO"
inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r ~/Desktop/testing | \
  while true; do
    read TMP
    echo "${TMP}" >> ~/Desktop/eventlog
  done
```

Note that inside the while loop I do want to have access to the event.

It seems to me that a pipe is necessary because we need to write with one process and read from another. But maybe there exists a trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` 4.2, you can set the `lastpipe` option to allow the `while` loop to run in the current shell instead of a separate process.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r ~/Desktop/testing |
  while true; do
    read TMP
    echo "${TMP}" >> ~/Desktop/eventlog
  done
```

(You don't need an explicit line continuation after the `|`, since `bash` knows that a line cannot end with that character.)

Comment: ah yes this does what I was trying to achieve. Interesting, I wonder how it is possible to implement that. I guess they don't create a new process but instead a new thread? It seems if one is writing and one is reading there must be two "somethings". I guess two threads.

Comment: No, just runs the first command in a new process and the loop in the current process instead of forking two new processes and waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct to assume that you are looking to avoid a secondary script so that variables modified in the for loop dont lose their value once the loop is done?

In that case you can just swap and so something like

```
while read TMP; do
  echo "${TMP}" >> ~/Desktop/eventlog
done < <(inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r ~/Desktop/testing)
```

but if you are concerned about flexibility of your code flow
you can redirect to a file handle and then read from that handle whenever
comment below if you want me to fish out en example

if it's something else - please add detail as to what you are actually looking to do

Comment: Thank  your for this answer. I will study it. I am sorry for lack of clarity in my request. I did not want for two processes to be run from the loop. chepner has the answer that I was hoping was possible. Kind regards.